# How to get the Auto-generated Key of my Unpacked Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am trying to access the auto-generated key of my chrome extension, and place this in my manifest file, as detailed in the section titled **Copy key to your manifest** at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.

However, in step 2, I cannot find the app ID shown in the 'installed apps and extensions' page in my user directory data (on macOS, the path is `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions`).

I was wondering how to find this key, as I cannot find the folder corresponding to my app ID in the user data directory. Thanks!

Comment: Go to chrome://extensions, activate developer mode in the top right checkbox and you will see the ID of your extension on its entry.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko I have found that ID, however what I can't find is the folder in the user data directory whose name matches the app ID of my chrome extension

Comment: @KaylenMistry Is the extension loaded as "unpacked extension" for development? In that case, the ID you see is just a temporary hash..

Comment: There is no folder in user data directory because it is an unpacked Chrome extension. You can use the ID you see in `chrome://extensions` page in your manifest, but bear in mind that, as @Xan pointed out, that ID will change once you publish your extension or if you change the directory it is loaded from.

Comment: I closed the question as a likely duplicate; feel free to ping me here if that's not correct.